# Power BI drill-trough button does not work on Ctrl+Click (left eye), but works on Ctrl+Enter?

Tags: powerbi, drilldown

I have Power BI drilltrough button (with action and destination) and it works on Ctrl+Enter, but does not work on Ctrl+Click (neither button of the mouse works). What can be the problem? How to debug this?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 options for the text of the button: `General - Title - Tex`t and `Button - Style - Text - Text` and both of them can be used for the button caption, but the important point is: `General - Title` is not serving as the active are in which the click can be made and that is why the `General - Title` is provided instead of the `Button - Style - Text`, then the click does not work. So - one should provide `Button - Style - Text` to solve the issue. So - you should know what you are trying to do, intuition may not apply!

Comment: Got me out of a hole this - answer is spot on.

Comment: I would have never in a million years thought it was something along these lines.